# configuring a REST wcf with anonymous auth

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, iis, web-config

I have a problem regarding a webservice that communicates in JSON with some client-side parts of a website
the webservice is inside the website solution, and using VB in aspx pages (web forms)

my web config is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>

      <webHttpBinding>

        <binding name="Binding1">

          <security  mode="None">
            <transport  clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>

        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>-->
    <services>
      <service name="Z60MRTR002.FrmCommandeAction" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="Z60MRTR002.FrmCommandeAction" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" ></endpoint>
          <!--<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />-->
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>

    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
            <!-- SOME SETTINGS -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and i activated anonymous auth on the IIS server.

It works fine on IISExpress(local) but not on my production server(iis6.0), help!

the error is:

[NotSupportedException: Les paramètres de sécurité pour ce service requièrent l'authentification 'Anonymous', mais elle n'est pas activée pour l'application IIS qui héberge ce service.]

in english : the security parameters for this services requires the "anonymous" authentication, but it isn't activated for the hosting IIS application

EDIT:
I copied and pasted the wcf to a new wcf project and i ppublished it on the server, making sure the anonymous auth is enabled. It tells me that auth isn't activated.

followed this:
https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f594e137-e2da-4b22-ab58-f8edba938802.mspx?mfr=true

just ask me if you need more infos.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error and it was nowhere near the web config, nor the server's config.I hactually had a sub function that called **HttpContext.Current.User** ...

the server returned the error even if it was activated:
so **to anyone that activated the anonymous auth and still get the error, you might have to double check your code :)**

I'm still not sure why it worked on iisExpress.Maybe the fact that it is debugging allows iisE to access the HTTPcontext.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure anonymous auth is enabled in IIS as per this:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: it is activated for the whole website , as said under the code.
I was wondering, can't the fact that the webservice is "in" the website be an hindrance to the access of a anonymous user?

Comment: maybe i should rename the question, since it looks like it's authentication problems, shouldn't i?